# Exception on integrating Hibernate3.2 with Struts2 and Tiles2 framework

Tags: struts2, tiles2, hibernate3

I am getting the following exception when I am adding Hibernate jar to Struts2 with Tiles integrated web Application :

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you post the block of code where the exception is being triggered?

Comment: Did you use plugin for tiles2?

Comment: @Chris - Actually I am using MyEclipse to integrate my Project.
When I am adding Hibernate Project Capability in project and deploy the application,immediately this exception occurs.

Comment: @RomanC - I am using MyEclipse IDE and adding the libraries of struts2 and tiles and their plugin from MyEclipse by adding  Project Capabilities

Comment: Post `web.xml`, libraries of deployed application, and full stacktrace.